# SQLite failing in Release mode on Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, sqlite-net

I'm using `sqlite-net` 1.0.8 in my `Xamarin.Android` application. It works fine in `Debug` mode, but when I switch to `Release` mode the following lines (default for `Xamarin`) in `AsseblyInfo.cs` switch off the debuggability of the assembly:

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: Application(Debuggable=true)]
#else
[assembly: Application(Debuggable=false)]
#endif
```

Because of this, many operations of `SQLite` fail due to `System.Diagnostics.Debug` being missing, for example this code:

```
using(var db = new SQLiteConnection(path))
    db.CreateTable<Cache>();
```

Throws the following exception:

```
[MonoDroid] System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.Debug' from assembly 'MyApp'.
[MonoDroid] at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable (System.Type,SQLite.CreateFlags) <0x002d3>
[MonoDroid] at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable<MyApp.Cache> (SQLite.CreateFlags) <0x0002b>
[MonoDroid] at MyApp.SQLiteCache..ctor (Android.Content.Context) <0x000c3>
[MonoDroid] at MyApp.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x0008b>
[MonoDroid] at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_yApp_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0005b>
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.d0784c17-eb18-447e-beb0-3e9d001bfee1 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00043>
```

I can see the following ways to handle the situation:

1. Add analogous `#defines` to the `sqlite-net` and submit a `pull requests` to its author
2. Add analogous `#defines` to the `sqlite-net` and keep them to myself
3. Remove the `#define` in `AssemblyInfo.cs` and keep the debug code in `sqlite-net`

What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Not exactly sure what the problem is by you but often when you are encountering issues just in release mode the issue is related to the linker stripping out too much. See if changing the linker settings fixes the issue.

Comment: @Jack I believe that stripping of `System.Diagnostics.Debug` is very much intentional and is meant as a protection against malicious users, so the question is more about how to live with it properly than about fighting it. Right now I've chosen the second option -- modified the source and kept it to myself

Comment: I wasn't referring to the stripping of the `System.Diagnostics.Debug` but rather to other classes/methods which the linker might not detect are being used. It's worth a try since it's a simple setting change. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/

Comment: @Jack oh, thanks for the suggestion) As it turns out, my project had the linker turned off (via the `Don't Link` option), so it should not have been the culprit here

Comment: @SanD I've also been having this problem (Link SDK assemblies is on) and I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to do so. I've even removed all Debug. calls from my app. how did you go about it if you can tell anyone. Its so f'ing weird that if I wasn't so far into the project I'd just rewrite everything in straight java and be done with it.

Comment: @Raigex I've just wrapped all calls and `usings` of `System.Diagnostics` in `#if DEBUG` / `#endif` and it's working just fine. I'm just not sure this is the *right* way to solve this problem

Comment: @SanD I actually removed all those calls and for some reason they are still somehow called

Comment: @Raigex Try to clean / rebuild in Debug mode, then in Release mode. Xamarin is wacky this way.

Comment: @SanD Thanks for the help. it turns out I just needed to do this crazy uninstall, restart device, install, check if works, and repeat if doesn't (the clean rebuild probably helped too) thing. I thought Xamarin was a more mature platform than it has been to acting to me.